# Acessar banco de dados local com Electron?

Tags: aplicação-desktop, electron, persistência

Ao desenvolver uma aplicação desktop, pode ser necessário acessar o banco de dados local.
O Electron, possibilita utilizar-se HTML, CSS e JavaScript. O HTML e CSS não é possível  e o JavaScript não é recomendado.
Como é feita a persistência em aplicações com o Electron?

Comment: Com *JavaScript*, inclusive você pode utilizar projetos como [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) para tal função.

Comment: Obrigado @ValdeirPsr, era isso mesmo que queria saber. Vou ver o que melhor atende minha necessidade.